# How to set the File Manager in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, file-manager

I've been using `Show in file manager` option in Idea actively enough. But some time ago it has got broken suddenly: now it opens "Sublime 2" text editor instead of "Thunar" file manager. Where can I configure this?

Answer (score 4):

Check the default File Manager for your desktop environment.  On Fedora with Gnome, I used the following command:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

In my case it showed Dolphin, which is not what I wanted:

> org.kde.dolphin.desktop

To change it to Nautilus I then ran the command:

```
xdg-mime default org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop inode/directory
```

Re-launch IDEA for the changes to take effect.

You can also check your default File Manager by opening it with the command

```
xdg-open ~
```

Which will open your home directory with the default File Manager.

The user settings are stored at `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason Sublime changed the association for the "folder" type.

On Ubuntu / Mint, the best way that I found is to use ubuntu-tweak. From this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11364855&postcount=23

- UbuntuTweak -> File Type Manager -> All -> folder
- click edit
- click  add
- change to Nautilus [or your file manager] ( also called File
  Browser )